# How to display french letters in list view?

Tags: android, listview, utf-8

How to display the French word such as  À, ó, etc in list view? I have tried setting it to UTF-8 before the data is read from the txt file to be inserted into the database and when the data is retrieved from the database to be displayed on the list, it doesn't seem to be able to display those letters in a correct manner but show those diamond shaped question mark when I tested it on my device.

InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.test);
 BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

Could someone please teach me how to fix this ? thank you.

Comment: `I have tried setting it to UTF-8 before the data is read from the txt file` You should make sure that the txt file is **written** with UTF-8 encoding, instead.

Comment: umm, how do i check if the txt file is written in UTF-8 encoding? ty

Comment: Modern text editors normally offer an option called "Save As". From there you can choose the saving encoding

Comment: YAY! it worked , tyvm for your help =).

Comment: I'll make an answer out of it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`I have tried setting it to UTF-8 before the data is read from the txt file` - You should make sure that the txt file is **written** with UTF-8 encoding, instead.

Most modern text editors offer an option called "Save As".
From there you can choose the saving encoding.

Comment: May I ask the downvoter the reason? The answer has been accepted, it doesn't deserve disliking.